# Montar tela em Android

Tags: android, android-studio

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em android e estou em uma parte que preciso colocar muitos itens na tela e para que não fique muito bagunçado, pensei em montar uma tela com o estilo da imagem que esta abaixo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Selecionando os itens a esquerda e mudando a direta, procurei na internet mas não achei, aguem poderia me ajudar como que posso montar neste estilo.
Estou utilizando o Android Studio, para desenvolver.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Essa tela usa a classe [**Fragments**](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html).

Você pode combinar vários *fragments* em apenas uma *activity* para construir uma interface gráfica com vários painéis. Além do mais você pode reutilizar seus Fragments em múltiplos *activities*.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Você pode pensar em um *fragment* como uma seção modular de um *activity*, que tem seu próprio cilco de vida, recebe seus próprios eventos de entrada, e que você pode adicionar ou remover enquanto o *activity* está rodando. É um tipo de *sub activity* que pode ser reusado em diferentes *activities*.

Fonte: [Fragments | Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

Fonte extra: [Multi-pane development in Android with Fragments - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFragments/article.html)

Comment: Valeu...Vou começar a estudar aqui para implementar.

Answer (score 0):

Embora a abordagem de Fragments seja correta, o print que você anexou parece ser de uma tela de Preferências.

Se você estiver realmente utilizando PreferenceActivity ou PreferenceFragment, a opção recomendada é usar PreferenceHeaders: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html#PreferenceHeaders